# size limit with output redirection or files created with fopen?

Tags: c

Redirecting the output of a program to a file:
program > file.log 2>1&
Does not include all the rows I see when running on the console without redirection.There are no errors . Windows 10. Roughly get 50k rows in a file of 1,800 KB.

- I get more rows in the file if I reduce the size of each row (rounding of numbers(.
- I did try handling the file directly with fopen, but I still not get all the output.

program > file.log 2>1&

Expected result: see in the log file the same output I see displayed on the console.

Actual result: a log file that is truncated, either by redirecting the output console or creating the file directly with fopen. No issues seen on sterr or running the program in debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

Having done redirection a lot, I can say with reasonable confidence you have one of exactly four issues.

1) You ran out of disk space.

2) You ran out of disk space quota.

3) You reached the maximum file size for that volume. Note that FAT32 (includes almost all USB sticks) has a maximum file size of 2GB.

4) You are saving to NTFS and need to defragment your hard disk.

Comment: I haven't encountered these, but they seem good to know! Are 1-3 OS-specific? What is the disk space quota? Just wondering.

Comment: @JonathanLam: They're properties of the filesystems; not OS specific. I suppose it's *possible* you have a broken library that can't handle standard output > 2GB but I haven't seen one of those in decades.